# Evaluate a string as condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle11g, conditional-statements

For istance, if I have a string like

```
my_string := ' ''a'' = ''a'' and 1 > 0 '
```

I can get it evaluated doing something like this in a procedure/function

```
execute immediate 'select CASE WHEN(' || my_string || ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END from dual'
```

But is there a way to do that without using execute immediate? Is there a way to evaluate a string like it was written in a query?

I want to this because I have generic conditions in a table like "COD1 like '%x%' OR COD2 = 'Z'". So I do some replace with this strings but then I would like to have them evaluated with the costraint to not use a user definied function, so no "execute immediate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but ... you effectively have to write your own expression parser:

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c, d) AS
SELECT 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE filters (filter) AS
SELECT 'a = b AND c <= d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a < b AND b < c AND c < d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a < ''y''' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c LIKE ''%y%''' FROM DUAL;
```

and you want to apply the `filters` to `table_name` then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
WITH split_filters ( id, filter, left_operand, operator, right_operand, expr, num_expr ) AS (
  SELECT ROWID,
         filter,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           3
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           4
         ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           'i'
         )
  FROM   filters
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         filter,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           expr + 1,
           'i',
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           expr + 1,
           'i',
           3
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           expr + 1,
           'i',
           4
         ),
         expr + 1,
         num_expr
  FROM   split_filters
  WHERE  expr < num_expr
)
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT MAX(filter) AS filter
         FROM   (
           SELECT id,
                  filter,
                  CASE 
                  WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'A' THEN t.a
                  WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'B' THEN t.b
                  WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'C' THEN t.c
                  WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'D' THEN t.d
                  WHEN left_operand LIKE '''%''' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(left_operand, 2, LENGTH(left_operand) - 2), '''''', '''')
                  END AS l_op,
                  operator AS op,
                  CASE 
                  WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'A' THEN t.a
                  WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'B' THEN t.b
                  WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'C' THEN t.c
                  WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'D' THEN t.d
                  WHEN right_operand LIKE '''%''' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(right_operand, 2, LENGTH(right_operand) - 2), '''''', '''')
                  END AS r_op,
                  num_expr
           FROM   split_filters
         )
         WHERE CASE 
               WHEN op = '='    AND l_op =  r_op THEN 1
               WHEN op = '!='   AND l_op != r_op THEN 1
               WHEN op = '<'    AND l_op <  r_op THEN 1
               WHEN op = '>'    AND l_op >  r_op THEN 1
               WHEN op = '<='   AND l_op <= r_op THEN 1
               WHEN op = '>='   AND l_op >= r_op THEN 1
               WHEN op = 'LIKE' AND l_op LIKE r_op THEN 1
               END = 1
          GROUP BY id
          HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(num_expr)
       );
```

Which outputs:

> | A | B | C | D | FILTER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | x | x | x | x | a = b AND c <= d |
> | x | x | x | x | a < 'y' |
> | w | x | y | z | a < b AND b < c AND c < d |
> | w | x | y | z | a < 'y' |
> | w | x | y | z | c LIKE '%y%' |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d4b30073a081ffa58e3fa1ec528faf4)*

---

In Oracle 11g, you could re-write it as:

```sql
WITH split_filters ( id, filter, left_operand, operator, right_operand, expr, num_expr ) AS (
  SELECT ROWID,
         filter,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           3
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           1,
           'i',
           4
         ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           'i'
         )
  FROM   filters
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         filter,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           expr + 1,
           'i',
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           expr + 1,
           'i',
           3
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           filter,
           '(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)'       -- left_operand
           || '\s*([<>!]?=|[<>]|LIKE)'                 -- operator
           || '\s*(''([^'']|'''')*''|[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)' -- right_operand
           || '\s*($|\sAND\s+)',                       -- expression concatenator
           1,
           expr + 1,
           'i',
           4
         ),
         expr + 1,
         num_expr
  FROM   split_filters
  WHERE  expr < num_expr
),
operand_substitutions (t_id, f_id, a, b, c, d, filter, l_op, op, r_op, num_expr) AS (
  SELECT t.ROWID,
         f.id,
         t.a,
         t.b,
         t.c,
         t.d,
         filter,
         CASE 
         WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'A' THEN t.a
         WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'B' THEN t.b
         WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'C' THEN t.c
         WHEN UPPER(left_operand) = 'D' THEN t.d
         WHEN left_operand LIKE '''%''' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(left_operand, 2, LENGTH(left_operand) - 2), '''''', '''')
         END,
         operator,
         CASE 
         WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'A' THEN t.a
         WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'B' THEN t.b
         WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'C' THEN t.c
         WHEN UPPER(right_operand) = 'D' THEN t.d
         WHEN right_operand LIKE '''%''' THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR(right_operand, 2, LENGTH(right_operand) - 2), '''''', '''')
         END,
         num_expr
  FROM   split_filters f
         CROSS JOIN table_name t
)
SELECT MAX(a) AS a,
       MAX(b) AS b,
       MAX(c) AS c,
       MAX(d) AS d,
       MAX(filter) AS filter
FROM   operand_substitutions
WHERE  CASE 
       WHEN op = '='    AND l_op =  r_op THEN 1
       WHEN op = '!='   AND l_op != r_op THEN 1
       WHEN op = '<'    AND l_op <  r_op THEN 1
       WHEN op = '>'    AND l_op >  r_op THEN 1
       WHEN op = '<='   AND l_op <= r_op THEN 1
       WHEN op = '>='   AND l_op >= r_op THEN 1
       WHEN op = 'LIKE' AND l_op LIKE r_op THEN 1
       END = 1
GROUP BY t_id, f_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(num_expr);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd178a99340d25a33e5543ec9d37ec7d)*

Comment: very interesting, I have also IN clauses and OR and AND concatenated, so I should improve the parser

Comment: @DomenicoF. The more you add the more difficult it becomes to implement. `IN` with literals on the right-hand side is not too hard; however, `IN` with columns on the right-hand side is much harder. `OR` adds the complexity of precedence and then if you add `()` braces around the logical operators to change the precedence then it becomes even more complicated. The easiest solution is to use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and skip having to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No way, as far as I can tell. That's what dynamic SQL (i.e. `execute immediate`) is used for.

---

For example, if you put just one condition (for simplicity) into a table:

```
SQL> select * from test;

MY_STRING
---------------------
 'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0
```

and cross-join it to another table (because, I'd expect *everything* to be returned as that condition is always met), you get an error:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept d cross join test t
  3  where t.mystring;
where t.mystring
               *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

while - if condition is literally put into the `where` clause, it *works*:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept d cross join test t
  3  where 'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           MY_STRING
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK       'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS         'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0
        30 SALES          CHICAGO        'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON         'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0

SQL>
```

So, dynamic SQL it is, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

> *is there a way to do that without using execute immediate*

You can use a substitution variable as an alternative method such as

```sql
SQL> SELECT CASE WHEN(&str) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  2    FROM dual; 

CASEWHEN('A'='A'AND1>0)THEN1EL
------------------------------
                             1
```

where `'a' = 'a' and 1 > 0` entered for `&str` whenever prompted

Comment: yeah but I need it in a scheduled job, can't use a prompt